# webContext in azure-devops-extension-api

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

Im attempting to create my first azure devops extension to plug a gap we have but I'll be honest I'm a little stuck.

I am using the new react templates from MS and have successfully created the shell of my extension that renders a tab item in the iterations board. This displays successfully in devops when deployed.

I now want to retrieve all work items for the visible iteration. I can see that the iteration id is available via the webContext. I can also see that its accessible via the VSS object, however the new typescript model takes a totally different approach:

```
public componentDidMount() {
    SDK.init();
    
    this.initializeComponent();
}

private async initializeComponent() {
    const projects = await getClient(CoreRestClient).getProjects();
    this.setState({
        projects: new ArrayItemProvider(projects)
    });
}
```

for example.

Does anyone know out there how to get the webContext using the SDK object or how I would go about getting the current displayed iteration id, project and team....so i can at least use a wiql query to get what i need?

Any help is appreciated.

Lee

Comment: Check my answer out here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73808484/567547  It's possible they've updated the package features in the api and sdk packages, but was at least able to drill down into the teams.  In regards to the interation id, it might be packaged up somewhere in the `Board` api, but so far, the only way I've been able to figure out how any of this works is to skip the docs and go straight to the source code in the node module and poke around.

Answer (score 0):

I have been wrestling with the same issue. I have discovered that this isn't supported yet in the new SDK. Just to try something out I forked the sdk and modified it and I am able to get the webContext. However I myself am trying to develop a Dashboard Widget and realized that getting webContext was just one of many things that are missing from the new SDK. Hopefully Microsoft will do something to complete this new SDK - there are many comments under the issues tab of their git repos with people complaining about how unusable it is.